# Output post for second wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress-theming

I recently added a new editor to all my pages and posts admin area with the Wordpress 3.3 new feature to do this

```
add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'my_second_editor' );
function my_second_editor() {
    // get and set $content somehow...
    wp_editor( $content, 'mysecondeditor' );
}
```

My question is how do I output what I enter in this second editor on my website/page?  Do I need to make a custom loop?  The codex is not very helpful unfortunately.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `get_post_meta()`, use it like:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'mysecondeditor');
```

Read more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

To save the data entered in your second editor you'll need this code in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post', 10, 2 );
function save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mysecondeditor', stripslashes( $_POST['mysecondeditor'] ) );

}
```

So after that he's the full code for your second editor:

```
wp_editor( get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'mysecondeditor', true), 'mysecondeditor' );
```

The `true` above makes sure only a single variable is returned and not an array so you can use it right away.

Comment: hmmmm, that seems like it might work but my second text editor seems to loose the content when I reload my page and al I get are the words array posting o the page and not what I enter in the second editor.  Do I need more code than jsut the add action I entered i my eaxample above for the second editor to work?  I will answer teh question I just need that alirified first

Comment: Yes, to show the text inside the editor on a save you'll need to hook into the `save_post_data` I'll update my answer

Comment: Sorry but all that did is place the editor on the front end of my website so the whole world can see it.  It also still does not hold any data.  What am I missing here.  I kept my origional code above in functions then added your code to functions like you said.  then added the echo get_post_meta you changed above

Comment: There's probably another problem with your functions.php file, the code above works.

Answer (score 0):

user2019515I's (Apr 18 '13 at 12:06) answer works for me, I can add text and gallery, but when I display that with this code:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'mysecondeditor')['0']; ?>
```

I got gallery code instead of the images, so:

```
mytext   [gallery ids="102,62"]
```

How could I display the text (mytext) and the images too?

Comment: OK, I could solve it with this code:

<?php
 echo apply_filters('the_content', get_extended(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'mysecondeditor')['0'])['main']);
 echo get_post_galleries($post)['1'];
?>

So I have two editor in a custom post type and I can display separately the second editor's content with displaying second editor's gallery too.